# Как получить с термометра данные о температуре, используя node-hid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Я пытаюсь работать с термометром с помощью [node-hid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-hid).

Модель устройства: `TEMPer1f`.

Считываю температуру, получаю Buffer:

```
<Buffer 80 40 0a db 0e e8 00 00>
```

Приблизительное значение в градусах: `27,5`

Мне нужно преобразовать любой буфер, который я получаю от датчика термометра, в градусы.

Comment: Посмотреть в документацию к термометру что и в каких единицах он выдаёт

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском. 3

Comment: https://github.com/asmuelle/node-temper1/blob/master/index.js#L43

Comment: понятное дело, нужно читать datasheet устройства

Comment: Я очень слабо разбираюсь в работе с устройствами. Это первый опыт. Модель устройства TEMPer1f. Тот код, что был скинут ранее выводит неверные данные

Comment: попробуйте в стороне https://github.com/asmuelle/node-temper1 и https://github.com/mlucool/temper-usb. можно будет узнать кто из них возвращает "правильный результат" и подглядеть подход к обработке данных с термометра